# How to center DataGridColumn text (not header) to center?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've this `DataGrid` structure:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                              CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                              CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                              CanUserResizeRows="False"
                              BorderBrush="DimGray" 
                              BorderThickness="1"
                              IsReadOnly="True"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding MatchStats}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                              Width="255" 
                              Margin="10, 10, 30, 0">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Path = PlayingMatch}"  >
                            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="85" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        ...
```

what I need to do is set the `DataGrid` text of the row to center. I actually managed this situation in the header, but I'm not able to do this for the rows. I saw other similar questions on stack, but all of these use the `textblock`, and I doesn't use any textblock how you can see in the image.

Is possible do this?

Actual result:

[image]

The three 0 should go to center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following style in your windows.resources section

```
  <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridCell}" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridTextColumn is build with a TextBlock for the Text. So when NOT changed (like the code you provided) it will work with TextBlock.TextAlignment.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:TypeDataGridCell}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```